# Netbeans IDE sometimes stopped auto-uploading. How to enable it?

Tags: netbeans

Sometimes the connection to the server has problems and the automatic uploading feature just goes away. When this happens the file cannot automatically get uploaded after editing.

How can I re-enable automatic uploading? The only way I know is to restart the netbeans IDE. Is there a better, faster way?